# creating python library zip for aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have some python code that has been developed using visual studio.  I want to run this python code as a lambda function in aws.  To do that I need to create a zip package with the code and the libraries that it uses.

Can I simply copy the package dependecies from their installation directory into another directory and then zip it to upload to aws?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html#python-package-create-with-dependency

Your dependencies need to be at the root of whatever directory you are uploading.

```
deployment/
├─ handler.py
├─ dependency1/
│  ├─ ...files
├─ dependency2/
│  ├─ ...files
```

So what Amazon essentially gets is all of the code in a flat directory.

---

A much easier method for development is using AWS Sam to build and deploy these packages for you. Then all you need is a requirements.txt and it will automatically package and deploy it for you with the following commands.

You do need to learn the template format (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html) but it massively speeds up your development in terms of ease of recreation of your functions.

Here is an example for the above function:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: handler.main
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: .
```

Then all I *need* in my directory is `handler.py`, a `requirements.txt` with `dependency1` and `dependency2` in it, and the above template (named `template.yml` by default)

Then you can use `sam build` to build, `sam local invoke` to test, and `sam deploy` to deploy to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the "requests" module in this example.

1. Navigate to the project directory containing your lambda_function.py
   source code file and run the following command.

> pip install --target ./ requests

2. All dependencies will be created in your project directory.
3. Zip them all like the below structure.

> ├my_deployment_package.zip
> ├──bin/
> ├──requests/
> ├──...AllOtherFolders/
> ├──lambda_function.py

4. Upload the zip file in your lambda function.
5. You can edit the lambda_function.py file in the AWS console from then on.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you want to separate the dependancies from the actual code you can put them as layers. AWS Lambda provides this sharable layers which can hold the depandancies. There depandancies can also be used accross different Lambda functions as well if required.

Follow the documention below from aws about creating layers for Python.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

For better maintainbility, you can also SAM or CDK for automatically pushing changes to the Lambda without manually uploading a zipped version. Thanks!

Comment: whats the process for getting the dependancies into a zip file.  For example if I need to use the requests library, can I copy the requests folder into another folder and then zip it up or do I need to install to that folder using pip and then zip it up.  I find the aws documentation to be unclear.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-cloud-architect/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

Comment: See if the link above helps for creating layers with depandancies. If not will try to explain the process.

Comment: ok so I followed the example and it worked.  If I need import requests library do I do the same thing - just copy requests library folder (and related folders) and zip it up and upload to aws?

Comment: when I try to install requests tomy folder I get this error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe: No module named install.__main__; 'install' is a package and cannot be directly executed

what does this mean?

Comment: I got this working finally.  Thanks everybody for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you got it to work, but would you mind sharing the approach so it will help someone who might have a similar scenario. Thanks!